# Struggling with Clean URLs

Tags: 6, .htaccess

I am in the process of upgrading an old Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8.

I realize Drupal 6 is end of support but need to get the site working on my local Debian box, in order to work with it to get migration moving.

I have exported by Drupal 6 web files and databases and have imported them in my apache2 web server and MySQL Database.

All seems ok except clean urls will not work. If i enable Clean URLs(the DB table has this on from the previous working site) the pages will not resolve. If i update the variable table manually and turn clean urls off the site works.

I have mod rewrite enabled. From the command line, I ran

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I know its enabled as if i run the command again it advised the module is enabled.

i read that you need to run the following too

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Below “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” add the following lines:

<Directory “/var/www/html”>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This is my Drupal .htaccess file and i cant see anything causing an issue. It was working fine on the web hosting i had before they upgraded the PHP version of course :-)

```
#####################
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id$
```

I know this can be a pain to resolve but wondered if anyone had any pointers or sugestions?

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory “/var/www/html”>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are there really `“` and `”` characters in your site conf? Remove them. Unfortunately it's hard to tell what's going on exactly not knowing how you configured your local environment.

Comment: Is your dev box running a version of php that is compatible with Drupal 6? It may help seeing your dev site's VirtualHost settings (the one with the `DocumentRoot` directive pointing to your site's Drupal directory). The file itself should be in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, but it won't be read by Apache unless you have a symlink to it in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. The filename/symlink also needs to end in `.conf`.

Comment: @leymannx - They are there from the default Drupal config. see above, i included the default .htaccess
What local environment configuration do you need to know?

Comment: @runswithscissors - PHP 5.6 appears to be ok with Drupal 6 from what i have read.

Comment: @runswithscissors - ive added the sites-enabled file to my main post.

Comment: Move the `<Directory>` lines above the closing `</VirtualHost>`. I'm guessing you only have the `000-default.conf` file, and no other .conf files for specific sites. Your dev site's in a subdirectory of the webroot, like `/var/www/html/dev_site`, and url `http://localhost/dev_site`?? If so, then within the `000-default.conf` file, try changing all the paths to `/var/www/html/dev_site`. This config won't be good if you need multiple sites on your dev box, but it's a fast way to tell if this is the cause of the problem. You can remove the lines with "#" from the `000-default.conf` in your post.

Comment: I left out that after making the above changes to `000-default.conf`, the URL to the homepage should be `http://localhost`. If this doesn't work, then can you give an example or two of a URL for a page before you enable Clean URLs, what your dev site thinks it should be after you enable it, and what it should actually be if it was working correctly? Also please add a few details about your setup, like where the dev_site is hosted, how you are accessing it, and if your dev server is on your own computer (which I was assuming it was), then what is the operating system.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your posts.
I have edited my post to include the updated 000-default.conf, i removed the clutter(lines that are comments #).
My site is not in a sub directory its at the root, so /var/www/html

I dont have any other sites, so this is a bare bones Debian box i created on a VM. Its hosted on another PC in my network but the network adapter is bridged so i access it across my LAN via its IP.  http://192.168.0.62/

Comment: The test box is Debian 10, Apache 2, PHP 5.6, MySQL5.7

Comment: I can access pages like this:
http://192.168.0.62/?q=videos
http://192.168.0.62/?q=imageUploader
http://192.168.0.62/?q=MainGallery

These can be accessed with clean urls on. And are the addresses of these pages if clean urls is off.
The clean url is the same without the ?q=
So:
like this:
http://192.168.0.62/videos
http://192.168.0.62/imageUploader
http://192.168.0.62/MainGallery

Comment: I think it would make sense to remove from your question the `.htaccess` that you are not currently using, as well as the `000-default.conf` that still has the comments. Having multiple versions will make it very confusing for someone who hasn't read the comments first. Maybe removing all the comment lines in the `mod_rewrite` section in `.htaccess` would make it more readable. Do you have access to the  `<VirtualHost>` config on the production site? Maybe try testing mod_rewrite by sending all requests somewhere else: `Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"` (untested)

Comment: I no longer have that hosting, had to let it go hence i set up a debian VM for this purpose